# Outlook query for 1 thing in subject line and 2 things not

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, query

I use a browser to access my Office 365 email.  In my experience so far, the search syntax is the same as for the Outlook desktop application.

I tried the following search query:

subject:"meeting notes" AND ( NOT subject:ABC ) AND ( NOT subject:XYZ )

I should get messages with "meeting notes" in the suject, excluding messages with ABC or XYZ in the subject.  Unfortunately, the messages I get include those with XYZ in the subject.

What is wrong with the above query logic?  What is the correct query?

P.S. Handy references:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-search-in-outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da
- https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/searchcommands.htm

P.P.S. I found the following to work, but am not sure as to the reason why.  It would be helpful to know what is wrong with the original query because I'm relying on understanding the query syntax for future composition of different queries:

subject:"meeting notes" NOT subject:(ABC OR XYZ)

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, in outlook search logic, NOT = AND Not if you have multiple search criteria at the same time. Here's an example in the blog for your reference: [Boolean search with multiple criteria in Outlook (AND and OR statements)](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/boolean-search-with-multiple-criteria)[image]

Comment: What you say makes perfect sense, but that means the two queries in my posted question are logically identical -- as I would expect.  That bugs me a lot.  It means that there is something wrong with the logic parser or something wrong about the public understanding of the rules.  Either way, whenever I cobble up a query, I'm not sure what the search engine is actually doing.

Comment: It is by design. There's nothing we can do.

Comment: If it is by design, it means there are rules for the Boolean logic that is implemented. It would be nice to know those rules because it doesn't seem to conform with commonly accepted rules of Boolean logic. In normal boolean logic, *x1 AND (NOT x2) AND (not x3) == x1 AND NOT (x2 OR x3)*. These are the exact two patterns in my posted question, yet the results differ.